# How can I parse a table from a specific string using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

sorry for the noobish question.

I'm learning to use BeautifulSoup, and I'm trying to extract a specific string of data within a table.

The website is https://airtmrates.com/ and the exact string I'm trying to get is:

> VES   Bolivar Soberano    Bank Value Value Value

The table doesn't have any class so I have no idea how to find and parse that string.

I've been pulling something out of my buttcheeks but I've failed miserably. Here's the last code I tried so you can have a laugh:

```
def airtm():
    #URLs y ejecución de BS
    url = requests.get("https://airtmrates.com/")
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup_ = soup(url,  'html.parser')
    columns = soup_.findAll('td', text = re.compile('VES'), attrs = {'::before'})
    return columns
```

Comment: why are you doing 2 rewuests?

Comment: I don't know why I'm doing two requests. Must has been from old code I forgot to erase. Sorry about this nightmare of a code, dont look at it too much

Comment: The table on the webpage [airtmrates](https://airtmrates.com/) is generated by Javascript so I don't think you can parse the results just by requesting the data with requests, you need to use something like selenium to execute the code that generates the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is dynamic meaning you'll need the page to render before parsing. You can do that with either [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/)

I'm not too familiar with Requests-HTML, but I have used Selenium in the past. This should get you going. Also, whenever I'm tooking to pull a `<table>`, tag I like to use pandas to parse. But BeautifulSoup can still be used, just takes a little more work to iterate through the `table`, `tr`, `td` tags. Pandas can do that work for you with `.read_html()`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


def airtm(url):
    #URLs y ejecución de BS
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)

    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    df  = tables[0]
    df = df[df['Code'] == 'VES']

    driver.close()
    return df

results = airtm('https://airtmrates.com/')
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
    Code              Name         Method    Rate      Buy     Sell
120  VES  Bolivar Soberano           Bank  2526.7  2687.98  2383.68
143  VES  Bolivar Soberano   Mercado Pago  2526.7  2631.98  2429.52
264  VES  Bolivar Soberano      MoneyGram  2526.7  2776.59  2339.54
455  VES  Bolivar Soberano  Western Union  2526.7  2746.41  2383.68
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!